# truncated educational history on a PhD thesis Vita

Tags: job-search

My PhD thesis includes a required "Vita" section that includes educational background.  I'd like some feedback on omitting work completed prior to my most recent bachelor's degree, in an effort to avoid any hiring bias regarding my age or any perceived 'lack of direction'.  Please see below for details.

I have two bachelor's degrees, the second was completed immediately prior to my PhD, and closely-related.  The first was completed quite a while ago (I left academia for a while and did other stuff).  However, I do have a couple peer-reviewed publications in my previous area of study which were published following the completion of the first bachelors degree, but I've been omitting them from my CV.

Comment: I don't think anyone ever reads the vita included in a thesis.  Frankly, I don't know why institutions require it.  The more pertinent question is what to put on the CVs that you submit to potential employers when you apply for jobs.